# What design pattern is best employed to control a sequence of steps?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, serial-port

I have a winform tool that interfaces with hardware using a serial port.

The serial port is used to send commands to the the hardware, which will acknowledge the commands and sometimes return data.

To accomplish a task, several commands need to be sent to the hardware in a defined order.

I have successfully implemented the tool using a switch statement to control the sending of the commands. However, while this works, I can't help thinking that there is a better, more OO way of doing this - is there?

Current implementation is below:

Each case is a command that needs sending to the hardware.
Send method is passed a method to invoke and the ID of next step - which will be returned if command sent successfully.

- Tool will send a start session command to the hardware.
- Hardware acknowledges command.
- Tool sends a set direction command to the hardware.
- Hardware will acknowledge command.

etc.

```
MessageID nextStep = MessageID.IMS;

while (nextStep != MessageID.Stop)
{
    switch (nextStep)
    {
        case MessageID.ISS:
            nextStep = Send( new ISS_StartSession(), MessageID.IE386);
            RaiseProgressEvent(10); //percentage complete
            break;

        case MessageID.IE386:
            nextStep = Send( new IE386_SetDirection(Direction.BOTH), MessageID.IE378);
            RaiseProgressEvent(20);
            break;

       //etc

       case MessageID.Error:
            HandleError(); //abort task if necessary
            break;
    }
 }
```

Is there a better way to do this..?

Is there a well known design pattern I should look at?

Comment: Is the next MessageID being sent to the current `Send` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially if your send/receive operations are asynchronous, I suggest to use the Command Pattern. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334696/command-pattern-purpose/4338191#4338191) I explain why I find it suited for sequences of asynchronous operations.

Comment: Frank, as it happens the methods passed to the Send method above implement ( I believe) the command pattern. Each of these methods implements an ICommand interface and detail how to execute the command via the serial port. It is up to the calling class to know when the ICommands should be executed. It is this that I wanted to improve..

Comment: @Frank How to use response of Step1 in some further steps? and how to execute next Step when Step2 is finished?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a State Machine. There are lots of resources on the net about them. Have a look.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_state_machines

Answer (score 3):

I guess **State** is the DP you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the chain of responsibility pattern as the steps can be chained and you can control the links in the chain at the client level.