# How to stop QNetworkAccessManager from getting a reply C++

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, qnetworkaccessmanager

Hi I have a `QNetworkAccessManager` which I use to send request to get image data from server. This call is asynchronous. I do multiple calls with it. Each call is done by opening a new instance of `QNetworkAccessManager` So when a specific condition occurs I want to stop the `QNetworkAccessManager` from receiving the replies from its network requests. Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a new QNetworkAccessManager for each request but share the manager. It's usually fine to have just one. Of course one can have multiple if the application design suggests it - but e.g. managing multiple of them in a single controlling object is usually unnecessary. Just have one manager with the same lifetime as the object controlling the network requests.

To cancel running operations, keep the QNetworkReply* pointers QNetworkAccessManager::get/put/post return and call [abort()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#abort) when your condition occurs.
Connect to the [finished() signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#finished) to remove them from the bookkeeping (as otherwise you would end up with dangling pointers).

If that becomes too complicated, think about using the command pattern. [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334696/command-pattern-purpose/4338191#4338191) I describe why I find it particularly useful in this context.