# Qt. How to send multiple simultaneous requests from multiple proxy servers

Tags: qt, networking, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I have list of accounts in format login:password and list of proxies ip:port. My task is to authorize an account and verify some of its characteristics. 
It is simple to do if I have one connection.

By it sounds good if I will be able to send, for example, five requests (POST) from proxies A, B, C, D, E at the same time. Than, if some of them replied I can send request (GET) from the same proxies. If some of them replies I can check content of reply. When all requests replied I select new proxies and repeat the process until all accounts are checked.

So I want to implement something like multithreading queries.

I am using Qt 5.1.

How can I implement this? What to read, study?

Thank you.

( sorry for my English(: )

Answer (score 1):

[QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) supports multiple concurrent requests, there's no need for you to use multithreading directly unless that makes things easier on your end.

To track multiple subsequent requests belonging to each other, I'd suggest to use the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to group them: Each flow of communication to one of the proxies would be managed by a job object.

[See this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334696/command-pattern-purpose/4338191#4338191) where I describe why I find the command pattern useful, in a very similar context.